# Query last one year - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to query all my visitor for the last one year.

I've tried

```
$raw = Visitor
           ::whereDate('created_at','>', Carbon::now()->year-1)
           ->get()
           ->pluck('created_at');
```

**Note:**

> Carbon::now()->year-1 //------------->  2018

I keep getting all the vsiitors in my db.

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

Try it like this:

```
$raw = Visitor::select('created_at')
          ->whereDate('created_at','>', now()->subYear())
          ->get();
```

Notice that here I replaced the part `->get()->pluck('created_at')` with `select('created_at')` because you only want the values of that column. Your approach would get all the results in memory and then pluck the wanted values, the alternative just brings you your desired elements.

Comment: @kyo I've updated my answer, forgot to execute the query :D

Answer (score 2):

```
$raw = Visitor::whereDate('created_at','>', Carbon::now()->subYear())->get()->pluck('created_at');
```

When you do `Carbon::now()->year - 1`, it returns `2018`.
So the comparison is done like this: `2019-09-15 18:18:00 > 2018`

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `whereYear` for that.

```
$data = User::query()
    ->whereYear('created_at', now()->year -1)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('created_at');
```

whereYear - method may be used to compare a column's value against a specific year.

[see more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
$raw = Visitor::whereDate('created_at','>', Carbon::now()->addYears(-1))->get()->pluck('created_at');
```

Comment: what is it diff than mine ?

Comment: `addDays()`? Why days? And isn't `addDays(-1)` the same as `subDay()`?